# параметр Zoom в RemoteObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли в запросе к серверу передать zoom в качестве параметра?
Что то типа такого:

```
remoteObjectManager = new ymaps.RemoteObjectManager("http://localhost:1337/showfttb/?bbox=%b&zoom=mapZoom", {
    splitRequests: true,
    paddingTemplate: 'managerResponse_bbox_%b'
});
```

где mapZoom это:

```
 map.events.add('boundschange', function (event) {
    mapZoom = event.get('newZoom');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

просто все оказывается:

```
    map.events.add('boundschange', function (event) {
    zoom = event.get('newZoom');
    remoteObjectManager.setUrlTemplate("http://localhost:1337/showfttb/?bbox=%b&zoom=" + zoom);
});
```

Comment: Думаю правильней будет всё-таки использовать &z=%z параметр, в документации это написано https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/LoadingObjectManager-docpage/#LoadingObjectManager__param-urlTemplate

Comment: Вы как всегда правы! Просто в указанной ссылке данный параметр не описан.(

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/frontend-docpage/ вот здесь немного подробнее